# Dreamhost - mirror site while in development

Tags: dns, hosting, dreamhost

new to dreamhost here and have followed the wiki on this but still need some additional help if possible. I want to be able to preview a site while I work on it, before I point the live domain to my dreamhost server. I've added the domain via the Control Panel, and all my files sit in the directory, /home/user/mysite.com - which is correct I think. When trying to follow the wiki with regards the mirroring details, I find that the only option I have is as follows, where I can't change any of these details:

Create the mirror at: mysite.com
Mirror this site: existingsite.com

The existingsite.com is just a live site sitting on the same server space. Is there something I'm missing here? Probably a newb mistake no doubt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mirroring` is for you to point a domain to an existing site. Hence this means you can mirror on 1 site. ie. both existingsite.com and mirrorsite.com points to the same server space.

If you want to create a `development site`, you probably are talking about 2 installations.

In this case, a quick and dirty trick I use is to create a development subdomain, `dev.existingsite.com` and fully host it. You normally get a `/home/user/dev.existingsite.com` folder with this. When your site is fully ready, you can edit your fully hosted `existingsite.com` and point the `web directory` to `dev.existingsite.com`. A better way is to `SSH` in and move the files.

There's an option copy files over in the settings page. Anyway dreamhost live help is pretty good. This is definitely something they will answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is it not possible to view the development site via a server name or IP, without having to copy the files. On previous servers, I've been able to do things like go to http://serverIP/~domain-account-name to preview the site. Unfortunately I don't have the live chat option in my control panel

Comment: You can, if you own a domain, you can create as many subdomains as you want. If you don't even have a domain, I suggest you just spend that $9.95 to get one for testing. So much easier to work with and you can then play with the DNS settings etc.

Comment: Sorry actually you can. Just spoof your own `hostname` file to add `someuniquedomain.com` and set it to point to dreamhost IP. You must add `someuniquedomain.com` as a fully hosted domain. That way, you can minimize migration pains if you set your development site to have the exact same URL as your live one.

Comment: Thanks again :) I think I might have cracked it, pretty closely following your suggestion: I created a subdomain, newsite.existingsite.com - then I set the Web Directory for this subdomain to be the directory of the new domain, i.e /home/user/newsite.com. It's not working yet, hopefully changes taking effect. Does this sound like it should work?

Comment: Yep - that worked like a charm! So, this allows me to use a subdomain for testing without having to copy the files anywhere else for going live once the domain is pointed to my server.